# LottieCompositionCache Memory Usage and Clearing Strategy in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lottie, android-lottie

I am working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose and incorporating Lottie animations. In the Android Profiler, I observed some memory-related details related to the LottieCompositionCache, and I'm looking for guidance on understanding and addressing potential memory issues.

Here are the details from the memory dump:

**LottieCompositionCache - com.airbnb.lottie.model:**

- Allocations: 323,191
- Native Size: 0
- Shallow Size: 288
- Retained Size: 17,216,395

I have concerns about the retained size and potential memory usage, and I wonder if this could be impacting the performance of my app.

As a potential solution, I added the following code snippet to my Composable:

```
@Composable
fun LottieAnimation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    rawRes: Int,
    iterations: Int = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
    contentScale:ContentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
) {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
        LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(rawRes)
    )
    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
        composition = composition,
        iterations = iterations
    )

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            LottieCompositionFactory.clearCache(context)
        }
    }

        LottieAnimation(
            composition = composition,
            progress = { progress },
            modifier = modifier,
            contentScale = contentScale
        )
}
```

My questions are:

1. Can someone help me interpret the memory dump details related to LottieCompositionCache?
2. Is the added code snippet an appropriate way to manage memory and potentially reduce the retained size?
3. Are there alternative strategies or best practices for handling Lottie composition caching in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: Your memory dump shows a high Retained Size in LottieCompositionCache, indicating significant memory use by your animations.
Your code for clearing the cache in DisposableEffect is a good strategy to reduce memory retention. It's effective for managing resources.
Alternatives? Optimize your animations, avoid loading too many at once, and regularly profile memory usage. Balancing memory efficiency and app performance is key.